# Is Final Fantasy X the only game in the franchise where you can swap characters in mid-battle?

Tags: final-fantasy-10

I'm fairly sure that Final Fantasy X is the *first* game in the series where you were able to swap characters in and out during a fight, but I'm not certain if it's the *only* one.

Are there any other games in the series where swapping in "inactive" characters during a battle is possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, it is not. *Final Fantasy XII* lets you switch characters in the middle of battle in pretty much the same fashion - to replace fallen allies or just to alter who is taking the brunt of attacks.

I don't know about the ones that come after, but one's enough to say no. ♪

Comment: You can switch a live character out as well though, not only if they die? In FFX a character can only be swapped when it's their turn, so if they die you can't take them out without first raising them (and having them survive until their next turn).

Comment: @Chad Yes, you can swap out live characters. However, since there's no "turn-based" system here, instead the restriction is that you can't swap out someone who is being actively targetted by an enemy attack. But like FFX, you can't take out a character who is dead until you raise them.

Comment: Hmm, I'd completely forgotten about that.

Comment: @GraceNote Are you sure?  I remember being hit at way low level by a Thundara blast and my entire team going down, and the game prompting me to replace them with a new team.

Comment: @Jim I don't see that contradicting anything that I said. In case it is confusing, in the last sentence of my earlier comment, "take out" refers to moving *into* the active party, not out of it.

Comment: @GraceNote Aha, that clears things up.  Much appreciated!

Comment: @ChadBirch XII's system is actually more forgiving in this way than X's. In X you can only swap out a character on their turn when you have control of them, which means you can't replace a dead, petrified, confused, or sleeping character with a healthier one until after you remedy the situation. In XII a dead character can *always* be swapped out since they'll never be targeted, and the other ones may be if you're good/lucky. Plus, XII allows you to target reserve characters with healing spells and items so you can bring them back strong, while X doesn't.

Answer (score 3):

*Final Fantasy X-2* and *Final Fantasy XIII* both allow characters to freely change roles/jobs/classes/paradigms/*whatever* mid-fight, but not the characters.

Before the final battle in Final Fantasy VI (FF3 US), you were asked to make a list of all the characters in the game. When you moved from one stage of the fight to the next, any dead characters were swapped out for the next one on your list. This was a one-time thing that only happened for the final battle, though.

Comment: Similar thing happens in FFVIII during the final battle - Your KO'd characters get banished after a couple turns and replaced with another at random.